# Упростить этот код c вложенными циклами и условием

Tags: java

```
if (type == 'i') {
        for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < dimension; j++) {
                System.out.print(intMatrix[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    } else if (type == 'f') {
        for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < dimension; j++) {
                System.out.print(floatMatrix[i][j] + " ");
            }   
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Чего-то уж очень туплю. Не могу упростить.

Comment: Он вообще упрощается?

Comment: Что по вашему мнению, означает упростить? Ну на вашем месте, я бы уже использовал Java 8 + и через `array.stream().filter(line -> "i".equals(line))`, а дальше уже юзал бы `forEach` и т. д.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда вы хотите что-то упростить, нужно в первую очередь обратить внимание на дублирование кода. Как можно заметить, то, что находится в блоках `if`, очень похоже друг на друга, и назвать это можно условно «вывод матрицы».

Пишем функцию вывода матрицы, но возникает проблема из за того что в одной вариации метода мы должны выводить `int` переменную, а в другой выводить `float`. На помощь приходят обёртки. Это объектно ориентированные представления примитивных типов. В этом объектно ориентированном представлении есть иерархия, в которой `Integer` и `Float` являются числами и поэтому наследуются от абстрактного класса `Number`.

Значит можно подменять абстракцию конкретным классом во время выполнения. Как написал @Silento о том, что полиморфизм вам поможет. У `Integer` и у `Float` переопределён метод `toString()` который и вызывается при работе с потоком вывода в консоль. Если во время выполнения получиться так что вы в метод `makeItSimply` передали матрицу типа `Integer` то метод `toString()` вызовется у класса `Integer` и с `Float` и с другими типами-обёртками, которые наследуются от `Number` аналогично.

```
public void printMatrix(Number[][] matrix, int dimension) {
    for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < dimension; j++) {
            System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Вас не смущает, что `printMatrix(matrix, dimension);` в `makeItSimply` будет выполняться всегда?

Comment: @Feeco Вы про условие что ли? Ну я думаю это не сильно важно, автор сам может сделать как ему нравиться. Главное, что теперь он имеет один простой метод вывод матрицы.

Comment: @Feeco Ахахах ну да сори тут можно вообще без условий обойтись. Сейчас исправлю, спасибо за замечание. Утро... Утром ещё и не такое бывает.

Comment: @diofloyk а чем тогда ваш метод отличается от моего?

Comment: @Санаев использованием полиморфизма и наследования

Comment: @Санаев очевидно же, я описал всё в ответе.

Comment: Позволяет вызвать метод без необходимости заводить char переменную для контроля типа и как заметил @Feeco без использования каких либо условий вообще.

Comment: Так это стратегией патерном называется

Comment: ради небольшого метода как считаете стоит ли использовать паттерн и не убыточно это по отношению к памяти будет

Comment: @Санаев это не какая не стратегия, это обычное наследование и полиморфизм, советую открыть вашу стандартную библиотеку, затем открыть абстрактный класс Number внимательно посмотреть на него прочитать коментарии к нему, затем открыть класс Integer и проделать тоже самое и потом Float. Потом в действительности разобрать что же такое паттерн стратегия и после спрашивать а не затратно ли использовать паттерн, который тут не используется по отношению к памяти.

Comment: А зачем размерность передавать? Матрица массивом задана, у массива есть размер.

Comment: И как этим методом напечатать `int[][] intMatrix = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};` или     `float[][] floatMatrix = {{1.0f, 2.0f}, {3.0f, 4.0f}};`?

Comment: @NickVolynkin я с этим согласен, что размерность тут не обязательно передавать, но у автора вопроса зачем то есть dimension, я предположил, что возможно у него может возникнуть потребность не выводить матрицу целиком, а какую то часть. Если честно не понимаю откуда столько батхёрта с этим вопросом. Это уже троллинг какой то :D

Comment: @diofloyk так-то вопрос интересный. Я не писал на джаве два года, вот пытаюсь вспомнить, как через Stream API напечатать массив — сходу не получается вывести точно так, как у автора.

Comment: А ну в принципе вас понял

Answer (score 2):

```
public .......(){
 switch(type){
   case 'i':
      check(dimension,intMatrix);
      break;
   case 'f':
      check(dimension,floatMatrix);
      break;
  }

  public void checkC (...dimension,...[][]floatMatrix)
     for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < dimension; j++) {
             System.out.print(floatMatrix[i][j] + " ");
         }   
         System.out.println();
     }
     System.out.println();

  }
```

Comment: если хочешь еще упростить. используй ArrayList вместо массива и используй стримы с лямбдами

Comment: используй вместо if case. как написал парень ниже. будет правильней, избавишься от if

Answer (score 2):

```
void print(int args) {
  System.out.println(args);
  System.out.println();
}
```

Набросано на коленке - считайте псевдокодом. Однако идея проста:

Оборачиваете системный вывод в свой, можете заморочиться и написать логику вывода, чтобы он в конце цикла добавлял пустую строку, а не каждый раз.

Так же вместо `if` используйте `switch`:

```
switch (value) {
  case "i": //todo;
  break;
  case "f": //todo;
  break;
}
```

На данный момент пишу на `javascript`, за возможные синтаксические ошибки прошу прощения, но идея думаю - понятна.

Comment: в JS типы динамические, а тут все строго) Мне в функцию надо передавать либо массив float, либо int

Comment: @MartyMcFly так Вам полиморфизм в этом поможет. Перегружаете метод print - всё.

Answer (score 1):

Много разных вариантов. Через дженерики например. Но в вашем случае я бы написал так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < dimension; j++) {
        if (type == 'i') {
            System.out.print(intMatrix[i][j] + " ");
        } else if (type == 'f') {
            System.out.print(floatMatrix[i][j] + " ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
System.out.println();
```

Comment: а если размерность матрицы будет выше, не будет ли затратно все время проверять type?